# Recommendation for free cloud deployable BI tool

Tags: data-visualization, data-analysis

can anyone recommend a free cloud deployable BI tool that can be used to query data on Apache Spark & to read S3 files through Athena?

Answer (score 1):

There are not many so-called free BI tools. Most of the established tools claim to be free, but usually, it's a 30 days trial with limited features.

However, there are a couple of opensource tools you could try to see if it meets your needs; both of them are cloud-native and meet most of the companies security standards. From my personal experience, vizcentric BI is a bit more matured with gRPC, security features, email reporting capabilities, result-set caching capabilities, access controls & decent visualizations (I felt superset has slightly better-polished visualizations then vizcentric BI)

https://superset.incubator.apache.org/installation.html 
https://www.vizcentric.com/  (refer to GitHub link onsite for source code)